# How to exclude a file from a re-write rule

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have this in my .htaccess file in a subdirectory (www.example.com/test/.htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/d]+)/?$ index.php?state=$1 [QSA]
```

So the url:

www.example.com/test/CA/

redirects to: www.example.com/test/index.php?state=CA

But my problem is:  www.example.com/test/form.htm also redirects

Can someone tell me how to exclude form.htm from the rule so it goes to the actual file and not redirect?  Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I excluded html and php files as a condition by doing the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(php|htm)$
RewriteRule ^([^/d]+)/?$ index.php?state=$1 [QSA]
```